# Migration script failed for plsql query with Junit (h2 DB)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, plsql, h2, database-migration

Query working fine in,

1. postgres
2. add query in migration script when we started the application it get executed

But failing when i run through junit test case.

Below is the error

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "[*]DO $$\000d\000a  BEGIN\000d\000a\0009IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM config)=0) Then\000d\000a\0009   insert into config (enabled, max_duration, min_duration, created_timestamp, modified_timestamp) values(false, 0, 0, now(), now());\000d\000a\0009   insert into config_version (config_id, enabled, max_duration, min_duration, created_timestamp, modified_timestamp, action) values((SELECT id FROM config LIMIT 1), false, 0, 0, now(), now(), 'create');\000d\000a\0009END IF;\0009\000d\000a   END\000d\000a$$"; expected "DELETE, DROP, DECLARE, DEALLOCATE"; SQL statement:

```
DO $$
  BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM config)=0) Then
       insert into config (enabled, max_duration, min_duration, created_timestamp, modified_timestamp) values(false, 0, 0, now(), now());
       insert into config_version (config_id, enabled, max_duration, min_duration, created_timestamp, modified_timestamp, action) values((SELECT id FROM config LIMIT 1), false, 0, 0, now(), now(), 'create');
    END IF; 
   END
$$;
```

Comment: Please give some detail about your database version. Your script is working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5e4a76c73ae47ad36394b8b7d2c6b2a6).

Comment: We using h2 db to run test case, seems like all the postgres scripts cannot be used with H2. H2 supports only minimal.

Comment: Running test and production databases in different environments?

Comment: For Junit test case we using h2 db(in memory database). For Production we using postgres

Comment: Can you explain how you solved this?

Comment: @NagulanS, H2 only support minimal when i see the official website. We found some alternate way to execute this queries.